# A question on a result.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, affine-varieties, dimension-theory-algebra

I was messing around a little bit and I got his claim:

> **Proposition:** Let $X \subseteq  A_n$, be an affine variety. Then $\dim X=\text{height }I(X)$, where $I(X)$ is the ideal generated by $X$.

I know this is very similar to the result that if $B$ is an integral domain and a finitely generated $k$-algebra, where $k$ is a field, and $p$ and prime ideal in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, we have;

$$\text{height }(p)+\dim(B/p)=\dim B$$

Comment: Welcome! [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.)  It's also not exactly clear what your *question* is - this is a well-known result often found early on in algebraic geometry texts.

Comment: It should be the *codimension* of $X$ is the height of it's ideal. Note that $\dim(B)=n$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks, guys!. That really helped. (That sounded sarcastic. It wasn't. It actually did).